# Do duration damage spells stack with themselves?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, damage

If a creature is hit by multiple of the same continuous damage spell, would they all stack?

Take for instance [Acid Arrow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/acid-arrow), which does 2d4 for (CL/3, max 6) rounds. If someone was hit by two of these spells with a long enough duration, both would take effect, correct?

The same should be true for [Constricting Coils](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/constricting-coils) since each of them would force the affected person to make the save and then be free of the spell, or take the damage, right?

Comment: MORE DOT!  MORE DOT!!!

Comment: @mxyzplk It took me almost a year, but I finally realized DOT means damage over time

Comment: Sometimes knowledge is a slow burn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the [Acid Arrow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/acid-arrow) spell has a duration of several rounds, its *effect* is damage, which is instantaneous.

DM_Blake, on the Paizo forums, [explains it well](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2sfyj?How-does-Acid-Arrow-work#4):

> Oh yeah, damage always "stacks".
>
> Or more accurately, it doesn't "stack" at all because **damage is always instantaneous**. No, the spell isn't an instantaneous spell, but each round when it does damage, the damage itself is instantaneously applied which means **there is nothing to "stack"** - just subtract the HP from the target as the damage is applied.

While [DM_Blake](http://paizo.com/people/DMBlake) is not a Paizo employee, he is Executive Founder of [Goblinworks](https://goblinworks.com/), developer of the forthcoming *Pathfinder Online*. Given these credentials, I am reasonably confident that he has a good understanding of the rules.

*(All respondents on that post, and [another on ENWorld](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?125197-Do-multiple-Acid-Arrows-stack), were in agreement that that's how it works. There was no official Paizo response either way.)*

Comment: I think a stronger case can be made for multiple *Melf's acid arrow* spells doing their damage individually because the spell's a Conjuration school spell of the creation subschool; that means this particular spell creates an actual, short-lived, real-life thing rather than *just* magical acid energy.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Perhaps, but the spell's duration belies that argument; the acid damage would be suppressed in an AMF, because it's *not* instantaneous.

Comment: @Chemus Truthfully, I was just giving the answer somewhere else to go because, although I think his opinion is as valid as anyone else's in a similar position, I don't think the opinion of a third-party software developer has the same degree of rules authority as the opinion of a Paizo tabeltop RPG designer.

Comment: Agreed, third party is not as good as official. But there is no official clarification that I can find, so 3pp + forum consensus is (arguably) better than nothing.

Answer (score 6):

I find no ruling in the Core Rulebook [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm), so the general [Combining Magic Effects](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#combining-magic-effects) rules apply:

> **Stacking Effects:** Spells that provide bonuses or penalties on attack rolls, damage rolls, saving throws, and other attributes usually do not stack with themselves.
>
> *Same Effect More than Once in Different Strengths:* In cases when two or more identical spells are operating in the same area or on the same target, but at different strengths, only the one with the highest strength applies.
>
> *Same Effect with Differing Results:* The same spell can sometimes produce varying effects if applied to the same recipient more than once. Usually the last spell in the series trumps the others. None of the previous spells are actually removed or dispelled, but their effects become irrelevant while the final spell in the series lasts.

Neither spell provides a bonus or penalty, but the sections following the 'Stacking' segment are not **only** regarding bonuses, as evidenced by the section on *Multiple Mental Control Effects*.

So, the continuing damage would overlap, not stack, as each effect is indeed identical. The only benefit to multiple castings would be to continue the duration.

---

Clarification: *Damage dealt* always stacks, but multiple identical *effects **dealing damage*** do not stack.

Example:

> A creature hit by 3 [*acid arrows*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/acidArrow.html) takes 6d4 acid damage this round, and only 2d4 acid damage the next. This is because the acid damage is *caused by* a continuing effect, not an instantaneous residue.

Had the spell description shown "Duration: Instantaneous", and the rules text said "the acid conjured lasts for 1 round per caster level, unless neutralized, dealing 2d4 damage each round it lasts", then the cause of the damage *would* have stacked.

Comment: That limits the options for reusing some spells

Comment: @Fering I think that's kind of the point. I mean, the fighter must be made to feel he's contributing *sometimes*, after all.

Comment: That is actually a fair point to make Hey I Can Chan

Comment: I would argue that the passage you quoted isn't referring to damaging spells. Otherwise, you could argue that being hit by an Acid Arrow makes you immune to any other acid damage for that round ("same effect").

Comment: @Adeptus You have a great point. The other acid damage wouldn't be the lingering effect of the acid arrow spell. Indeed the initial damage from a second acid arrow would damage the target, but the lingering effect would only be the greatest effect from identical effects.

Comment: So... what? Roll both & keep the highest? I still don't think "effect" is meant to apply to damage.

Comment: The damage is a random number; the dice overlap. The only difference would be the duration; the longer duration would 'win. If you find something that contradicts the quoted source, bring it up, or post a competing answer.

Comment: +1; Using [Bleed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Bleed) as a template, you'll notice that even Bleed does not stack if it's the same type of damage. While I'm awfully surprised it works this way, because it's not logical, the RAW supports this position in other types of recurring damage situations.

Comment: @phyrfox Bleeding is a condition, so it uses the "stacking of effects" rules. Continuing-to-be-damaged-by-Acid-Arrow is not a condition. Acid Arrow doesn't impose any condition. It just does damage, multiple times.

Comment: I think Adeptus is correct in this instance, if you have multiple wounds filled with acid each one would be doing damage, I'm pretty sure the "Same effect with differing results" doesn't apply on damage or healing spells. Heals and damage take place instantaneously, and aren't subject to normal stacking penalties. Plus, Acid arrow conjures actual acid. Not magical acid.

And I'm pretty sure that bleeding does stack as well, as bleed damage sticks around until the target makes a heal check. If you nick someone in the artery they aren't gonna stop that flow anytime soon.

Comment: @Sandwich Check phyrfox's link re: bleed. The effect of the acid is akin to being on fire. How many times can you be on fire? Acid arrow is *not* an instantaneous conjuration, but one with a duration; it's an effect.

Comment: Acid arrow is very much a creation conjuration. When you hit something with a blob of low pH acid what happens? It burns them for a while. If you hit someone in two different places with the same spell, are you implying that one of the blobs of acid would just *stop* burning through someone?
-----------------------------
Same with bleed damage. If you damage someones femoral artery and someone's Brachial artery would you stop bleeding in both of those places just because you're already bleeding somewhere else? Hell no. You would bleed from those two arteries and within minutes you'd be dead.